# iPhone 5 won't ring

Tags: audio

My iPhone 5 will not ring when a call comes in. It is not set to vibrate on the side of the phone. What do I need to change in settings. I have tried all I know how. When i get a call the phone has no sound for ringer but when I select ring tone it has sound

Comment: I am sorry but your question of low quality as it is now. Try to improve it with at least list of detailed actions you already did.

Answer (score 2):

1. flip Ring/silent switch at the left side, make sure keep the phone on "Ring" state.
2. launch the "Setting" App and check the following settings
3. "Sound", check the volume of ring and alters
4. "Do not disturb", make sure disable this feature
5. "Phone" ->blocked, make sure the caller is not in the blocked list, or call forwarding, call waiting, e.g.